# JSF modification in Groovy way?

Tags: jsf, grails, groovy

Somewhere in Grails family I had a lecture about conneting JSF / Groovy / Grails. I.e. less configuration, more convention, Groovy session bean returning "next" navigation link etc.
Very interesting at intellectual level, but i think these tools have acceptance by totally different teams / people. JSF (standard, certified etc) in corporate programming, G* technologies at small, independent development.

Meet anybody real project using such mixing?

*(To understand my POV: in web programming I prefer Wicket, JSF in prototype, I'm quite new in Groovy, and no real project in Grails)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have both JSF and Grails applications.  We are in the process of sunseting the JSF applications and all new applications in Grails.  I have read that the LinkedIn site used Grails on a larger projects with much success.  I am still on the Grails 2.X platform.  Switching developers from JSF to Grails was an easy transition for me and generally provides a large increase in productivity over JSF.  I highly recommend Grails over JSF.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand, "old" apps are as a whole JSF, and "new" Grail? I have lost this link, but blog say about smooth migration from one to the second, during process app is mixed. I don't believe in 100%, in my imagination very different environments. Can You confirm or negate?